# Back button goes always on an internal div

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm developping an Android application with Phonegap/Jquery mobile. I have an Html file that contains multiples pages :

```
<div data-role="page" id="products" >
    <div data-role="header" >           
        <h1>Produits</h1>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext"        data-direction="reverse"></a>                      
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <br>
        <ul id="cat-list" data-role="listview" class="mainmenu">
            <li><a href="#" id=198 >Electronique</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id=155 >Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id=163 >Bonnes Affaires</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="productsByCat"> <div>
```

My script files contains

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#products", function(){   

    $(this).find('a').unbind('click').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        passDataObject.selectedId = this.id;
        $.mobile.changePage('#productsByCat', { transition: 'slide'} );
    });
});
```

My problem is when i click on the back button in products Div, it displays the productsByCat div (the previous page is an external page Home). Some help please?

Comment: Using `pagebeforeshow` or similar events to add listeners e.g. `click` is a bad practice. Each time `products` page is shown, you duplicate `click` listener. Use `pagecreate` to attach listeners.

Comment: Thanks Omar, but I still have the same problem, each time I'm redirected to #produitsByCat. I putted an alert before $.mobile.changePage('#produitsByCat', { transition: 'slide'} );
and it is shown when I click on back button then #produitsByCat is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that by selecting the listview id on click event instead of  $(this).find('a') :

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#products", function(){   
        $("#cat-list a").on("click", function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           passDataObject.selectedId = this.id;
           $.mobile.changePage('#productsParCat', { transition: 'slide'} );
        });
});
```